# Find last remaining person in the game

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In a game, $N$ people are lined up in a circle and numbered from $0$ to $N-1$. At each turn, the next $K$th person, starting with the last eliminated person, is eliminated from the game. The first person to be eliminated is the $K$th.
Find the last remaining person in the game.
Example:

$N$ = 5, $K$ = 3

0 1 2 3 4

0 1 3 4

1 3 4

1 3

3

The last person is the 3rd one.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Very nice problem

Comment: Unless I am misreading, this is the classic [Josephus Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem)

Comment: I tried to solve this problem long time ago (with the only difference that I numbered from $1$ to $N$), but all I could find out was a recursion for the next eliminated person, no fast way to find out the last person if $N$ is extremely large.

Comment: I think that this might be very difficult or maybe impossible to calculate only based on N and K,pretty much like Ramsey's numbers for which,a formula doesn't exist yet.Unfortunatly I think that the recursion is the only way to find the number of the last person